# how to display the submitted data using $_POST

Tags: php, post, input, superglobals

I have an input named like this:

`name="ListPassengers[0].Lastname"`

How can I display the value, because when I use `$_POST['ListPassengers[0].Lastname']`

I get the following error:

> Notice: Undefined index: ListPassengers[0].Name in C:\wamp\www\3\res.php

Comment: `print_r($_POST);` — that will display everything in `$_POST` (in a prettier formatting if you wrap the output in `<pre>` tags)

Answer (score 0):

Use `print_r($_POST)`. You can also use [`print_r()`](http://php.net/print_r) for printing `$_GET` values as well as arrays etc.

Answer (score 0):

all the values passed from one page is stored in $_post variable and these are indexed with names which u have sent them so u just have to use those i.e input field name etc to refer its data

1. one way to post all data is same as given above of print_r().
2. u can also use  `var_dump($_POST)`
3. or u can access one by one using a for loop also

---

```
  `  foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
     echo $key.'='.$value.'<br />';      `
```